# WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly is not working on special characters

Tags: flutter

I am using `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly` in an input text to only keep digits
I set `keyboardType: TextInputType.number` too

If I remove `keyboardType: TextInputType.number`  and type for example `a` it removed immediately, Nice!

[image]

But in numerical keyboard When I type `,` or `.` or `space` or `-` , it not removed! I must type another digit to remove , If you repetitively type `,` you can have `,,,,,,,,` or `25,,,,,,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there isn't easy solution how to change keyboard layout.
But you can easy also to enter only digits and cursor will not jump to starting position.

Just create your own `TextInputFormatter`

```
class MyFilter extends TextInputFormatter {
  static final _reg = RegExp(r'^\d+$');

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return _reg.hasMatch(newValue.text) ? newValue : oldValue;
  }
}
```

and use it instead of `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Home())));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: [MyFilter()],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```